# instill a variable from the json_encode in a div by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

After retrieving a variable with `json_encode()` like this:

```
var foo = <?php echo json_encode(get_option('foo')); ?>;
```

I would like to incorporate it in an element with jQuery like this:

```
$(function () {$('#button').on("mousedown", '#button', get_json_encode);});
$.fn.get_json_encode = function () {$('#bar').text(foo);});
```

But I don't know why my `foo` var doesn't appear in my element `#bar` With `alert()`, it work...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `get_json_encode` and `$.get_json_encode` are two totally different things.

Comment: I suggest you to split the problem into two: 1) Make sure you are able to correctly echo the JSON value, so it will be assigned to `foo`. 2) Then, solve jQuery as a separate problem.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it's just the name of my function ! Not a good name ?

Comment: @PavelS. The first part of this problem is already solved, I can alert the JSON value normaly. It's the affectation of this value who suppose to be solved

Comment: @muramasa Good. So you can edit your questions and exclude PHP from it. There is a lot of PHP people who want to help out but questions like this make it harder. PHP is not closer to JavaScript than any else server-side language (Ruby, Python, Java). Would you mind editing your question an excluding the PHP part, if it has been solved before and the question is not really about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$('#bar').text(foo);
```

to:

```
$('#bar').html(foo);
```

Note I've changed `text` to `html`. I've rewritten the function below, which should work...

```
var foo = <?php echo json_encode(get_option('foo')); ?>;

$(document).on("mousedown", '#button', function(){
    $('#bar').html(foo);
});
```

Comment: `get_json_encode` is not defined. As Ohgodwhy says `get_json_encode` not the same as `$.fn.get_json_encode`.

Comment: @PhilCross It doesn't work... I tried your two functions, no two will give results ...

Comment: What type of element is `#bar`?

Comment: @PhilCross It work normaly if I change the type of my element from `div` to `input` and change the affectation from `html()` to `val()`... But for a `div`... No way !

Comment: Try the code in my answer again, if your using Chrome (or any other decent browser), `inspect` the `#bar` element to see what data it contains. Technically if you change it from a `div` to `input` and change `html()` to `val()`, it should work as expected in the method I've posted :-s If you can see the JSON in the div when you inspect the element, it might be due to some kind of css formatting?

Comment: I think that I keep your code, but I gonna to change my type of element in order to use `.val()` for the affectation. ;-) ! thank's !!